# Material Design Lite Dart, refreshing table

Tags: dart, material-design-lite

Is there a simple example of custom component in MDL Dart http://www.material-design-lite.pub using a data table or a list linked to a model changing over time?

I have the exception

```
     Exception: Uncaught Error: RangeError: Index out of range: index should be less than 6: 6
Stack Trace:
#0      HtmlCollection.[] (dart:html:17296)
#1      _ChildrenElementList.[] (dart:html:10623)
#2      MaterialRepeat.insert.<insert_async_body> (package:mdl/src/template/components/MaterialRepeat.dart:148:55)
#3      Future.Future.microtask.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:144)
#4      _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:43)
#5      _microtaskLoopEntry (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:52)
#6      _ScheduleImmediateHelper._handleMutation (dart:html:42503)
```

Using the custom [ToDo sample](https://github.com/MikeMitterer/dart-material-design-lite/tree/master/example/spa_todo) when updating the `items` list

Comment: You saw the following samples? http://samples.material-design-lite.pub/mdld_observe/index.html + http://samples.material-design-lite.pub/mdld_repeat/index.html If you still have problems - can you create a little sample on GH?

Comment: All these samples are using ObservableList...

Comment: Live-Sample is here: http://samples.material-design-lite.pub/spa_todo/index.html BTW: How do you update your items?

Comment: I'm developing a data table with repeating row from elements in a list ( https://gist.github.com/anonymous/fd69340fdb239218727c ) now I'm receiving DomRenderer excpetion Usually this error occures if content has not just ONE single root element.
DomRenderer: (17:59:42.142) Invalid content:
 <tr> <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">f8a9d0650822</td> <td>a</td> <td>b</td> </tr>
Usually this error occures if content has not just ONE single root element. Is there any sample using mdl data table?

Comment: OK, wait - I'll be back with a sample...

Comment: Hmmm - not so easy... the problem is the tr-tag. Adding tr to the DOM is context-oriented and this produced the problem. If you replace tr with a div it works but destroys the table. Would it help if I provide you with a DataDivTable (I would use css-classes instead of all the table elements - look and feel would be the same...) e.g. mdl-divdata-table--tbody or mdl-divdata-table--tbody--tr

Comment: I see, I have to arrange some data in a table way, better following MD guidelines. I'm opened to suggestions.